# using Favourite button with shared preference in Listview

Tags: flutter, dart

i have favourite button in list view when i clicked it and click all the items in the list , how i can fix that +  using shared preference here is my code :
in my stfl state :

```html
  static const likedKey = 'liked_key';

  bool liked;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _restorePersistedPreference();
  }

  void _restorePersistedPreference() async {
    var preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var liked = preferences.getBool(likedKey) ?? false;
    setState(() => this.liked = liked);
  }

  void _persistPreference() async {
    setState(() => liked = !liked);
    var preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    preferences.setBool(likedKey, liked);
  }
```

My LikeButton Code:

```
IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  liked ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
                  color: liked ? Colors.red : Colors.grey,
                ),
                onPressed: _persistPreference,
              ),
```

Comment: please explain your problem much clearer and with more details. No one understands your problem

Comment: I have listview like a posts ok ? every post have  button = like . when user click like button it change all the posts to liked ! clear?

Comment: I get it now. Thats because of all them share a variable called like. So when you change liked to true, all of them will be liked.

Comment: Yes Exactly can i dm you ?

Comment: I've posted an answer @Ramzi. You need to generate a List<bool> then change each individual value if the user presses the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem by generating a `List<bool>`. Since pressing the IconButton will change the value of liked, all of your icons will become Icons.favorite because they are all referencing the same bool which is your liked. Here is an example on how you can fix this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   List<bool> likedList=[];
   List<bool>.generate(yourItem.length, (i) => likedList.add(false);
   return ListView.builder(
    itemcount:yourItem.length,
    itemBuilder:(BuildContext context,int index){
     return IconButton(
             icon: Icon(
                      likedList[index] ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
                      color: likedList[index] ? Colors.red : Colors.grey,
             ),
             onPressed:()=> likedList[index]=!likedList[index], //toggle bool value
       );
     }
    )
```